# Whats is good accordion menu for SharePoint. Looking to replace the quick launch

Tags: 2013, 2010, navigation, managed-metadata

I am looking for something that uses the managed metadata as a source. The display should start off collapsed and expand when clicked on. Also the current managed metadata navigation is limited to just 2 depths. I would need something more robust. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the managed metadata navigation in the SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific. I need something to replace the quick launch menu.  Using the managed navigation leaves everything expanded. I am looking for something a lot more functional for large menus.

Comment: Is this your SharePoint 2013 site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 you can setup the managed metadata navigation for the "Current Navigation"

**Note**: You must enable the publishing feature to customize the navigation.

Here are the steps

1. Go to site settings
2. Click on "Navigation" under "Look and Feel" section.
3. Under "Current Navigation" settings select "Managed Navigation" option.
   [image]
4. Click "Create Term Set" button to create a new metadata navigation. Or select the terms set from the Taxonomy option if you have already created one.
5. Will proceed with creating a "New Term set". It creates one "Term Set" with your site name and highlights that.
6. Click on the "Term Store Management Tool" link below the Taxonomy selection box.
7. Create terms and create child terms also if you want to second level terms. Example as shown below

[image]

8. You have to set the each term with navigation links

[image]

9. You will see the current navigation after few minutes.

[image]

10. To collapse the parent nav items by defaults you need change settings in your master page.
11. Edit master page using an SP Designer. Go to "All Files -> _catalogs -> master page. Edit your master page and search for "QuickLaunchNavigationManager". In that control update the static and dynamic display levels as follows.

[image]

12. Finally, you will the navigation as follows
    [image]

Comment: Will this go more than two levels deep?

Comment: Yes. Try to increase the `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` number.